# Hand over variables to a website without a querystring

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, query-string

I have a  web-application (ASP.NET) and want to open another **external webpage** on another machine.  I have to **forward some information** (variables) to that webpage, but they should not be part of the URL. So my question is, how can I achieve this without **querystrings**?

Comment: Send a POST request to the external website?  Do you have control of the external website?

Comment: If you do have control, you may alternatively want to use cookies

Answer (score 3):

Session variable will only work on the same backend web server.  Your options are writing to a cookie or an HTTP POST.

Comment: Warning: Cookies will only work if the other machine is in the same domain.